# Is there way I can get static download link (for nuget) from codeplex?

Tags: nuget, codeplex

I need static download link for nuget itself (Command line thing) , ideally for nuget source tarball.

The only way I can see to get nuget from source is via git but I can't be sure in git version, I can get git version on some commit but I even want to avoid git requirement so I need to know if there are already some places where I can get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for the download zips is:

```
http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/SourceControlFileDownload.ashx?ProjectName=*projectNameHere*&changeSetId=*setIdHere*
```

So for the current build as of 7/28/2013 11:33 CST the link is

```
http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/SourceControlFileDownload.ashx?ProjectName=nuget&changeSetId=2764f6c71ea206a60eb136c27c04005975712c19
```

You must include the changeset id and there is no automatic way I know of to find the latest id. Getting the id's themselves is easy, just click the [History button](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and the changeset id will be in the address of the [changeset you choose](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/2764f6c71ea206a60eb136c27c04005975712c19).

Comment: weird that it downloads file named "`SourceControlFileDownload.ashx?ProjectName=nuget&changeSetId=2764f6c71ea206a60eb136c27c04005975712c19`"

Comment: No, it downloads a file called `nuget-2764f6c71ea206a60eb136c27c04005975712c19.zip` (this name is much more reasonable on projects that have smaller changeset names). What is happening is the [ashx page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) is a dynamic asp.net `handler` that has a some logic behind it. It reads in the variables `ProjectName` and `changeSetId` and it replies with the new file name and the bytes of the file you are to download.

Comment: well with wget it downloads unnamed thing so I must name it manually but it's fine, seems like.

Comment: try adding `--content-disposition` flag to wget [it may grab the correct name automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected), or use curl with the flags `-J -O`